# filter pandas data frame to drop according to list

Tags: python, string, pandas, filter

I have a dataframe like this with one column containing countries and other columns (irrelevant for the question), as below.

```
data = {"country": ["AA", "BB", "AA", "CC", "DD", "AA", "BB", "AA", "CC", "DD"],
"other variable": ["foo", "bar", "bla", "house", "fish", "car", "pet", "dog", "cat", "door"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
to_drop = ['AA', 'CC']
```

I would now like to filter on the column country and *remove* all *rows in a list* (here, country "AA" and "CC", many more in reality).

For one country only I would use `df_new = df[df['country'].apply(lambda x: "AA" not in x)]`, which works fine - but I can't figure out how to iterate over the list `to_drop = ['AA', 'CC']` containing the countries I want to get rid of.

Does anyone have an elegant solution I fail to see? I have checked all the 'filter pandas' questions without success.

Comment: df[~df.country.isin(to_drop)] works!!

Comment: You say there are many countries you have to drop and cant type it all down in "to_drop"?

Comment: @iamklaus, this weirdly doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and it worked

```
df_new=df[~df.country.isin(to_drop)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The only (not very elegant way) I came up with is

```
for i in to_drop:
    df_new = df[df['country'].apply(lambda x: i not in x)]
```